# How to make character interact with obstacles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know how to create a character and move it around in HTML Canvas, but I don't know how to interact with obstacles, as in jump on them or be blocked from moving any further.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do collision detection. Maintain the coordinates of each object in the game. When an object is about to move, determine if the new position intersects with any other objects.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Collision_detection

This would generally be handled for you when using a JavaScript gaming engine like [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) or [PlayCanvas](https://playcanvas.com/) .

Comment: Thank you for your feed back, this is exactly what I needed!